# FB.ui() gives errors unless display: 'popup' is specified

Tags: facebook, jsf, primefaces, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a really frustrating problem with displaying dialogs using FB.ui() within my Facebook app.

Basically I have the following function that I use to invoke the dialog window:

```
function postToNewsFeed(postName, postCaption, postDescription) {
FB.ui({
    method : 'feed',
    name : postName,
    //display: 'popup',
    link : APP_LINK,
    caption : postCaption,
    description : postDescription,
}, function(response) {
    if (messageGrowlWidget) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            messageGrowlWidget.renderMessage({
                summary : 'Post successful',
                detail : 'Your message has been posted to your wall.',
                severity : 'info'
            });
        } else {
            messageGrowlWidget.renderMessage({
                summary : 'Post failed',
                detail : 'Unable to post to your wall.',
                severity : 'error'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

};

Any time I make this call from within the facelet, the Facebook dialog box appears with a red background and the message "An error occurred. Please try again later."  However, if I specify display: 'popup', the dialog displays properly (but in an ugly popup).

If I make the exact same call from within a test HTML page (i.e., not using JSF/Primefaces), everything displays properly **without** setting the display as popup.  Due to extensive testing and the above observations, I'm certain that this is not a problem with how I've called FB.init(), or any of the redirect URI/link mismatches.

My guess is that there's some sort of collision or other conflict in the Javascript environment -- perhaps a variable is being overwritten by all the various scripts that are running in the Facelet.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get things working without resorting to popups?  I can probably use that as a fallback option, but the user experience is significantly poorer.

A little background:

- Primefaces 3.5
- Faces 2.1.17
- Facebook Javascript SDK

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One other note: setting display : 'iframe' also works.  It's much more visually appealing than popup, but it also interferes with sending the growl messages.  I'm probably going to wind up using 'iframe'.

Comment: i have the same problem but on a different environment, and when I logged out and logged in again, it worked. Now I don't know how to solve this problem for current users without forcing them to logout... :/